# Extjs - uploading file but the the screen stuck on "grey"

Tags: extjs, file-upload

I am succesfuly uploading a file with the extjs file uploading panel.

My problem is that after i upload the file, the waitMsg disappears but the screan in not focusing back on my app and its stuck in a grey screen.

[image: Example]

```
{
                                xtype: 'button',
                                id: 'btnUploadExcelBidId',
                                icon: 'images/V16x16.png',
                                text: 'load',
                                listeners: {
                                    click: {
                                        fn:  function(button, e, options) {
                                            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                                                title: 'Upload Bid',
                                                width: 400,
                                                bodyPadding: 50,
                                                margin: 300,
                                                frame: true,
                                                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                                                items: [{
                                                    xtype: 'filefield',
                                                    name: 'photo',
                                                    fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                                                    labelWidth: 50,
                                                    msgTarget: 'side',
                                                    allowBlank: false,
                                                    anchor: '100%',
                                                    buttonText: 'Select Excel...'
                                                }],

                                                buttons: [{
                                                    text: 'Upload',
                                                    handler: function() {
                                                        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                                                        this.up('window').close();
                                                        if(form.isValid()){
                                                            alert('starting upload');
                                                            form.submit({
                                                                url: 'UploadExcel.jsp',
                                                                waitMsg: 'Uploading Excel...',
                                                                waitMsgTarget: true,
                                                                success: function(fp, o) {
                                                                    alert('Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                                                                },
                                                                failure: function(fp, o) {
                                                                    alert('fail');
                                                                }        
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }]
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                          }
```

Comment: Can you post the source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comments in [the doc about waitMsg](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-cfg-waitMsg). There seemed to be a bug with 4.1.2, and there is a workaround posted by utopic and LDSP:

```
success: function(form, action) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg); you can optionnaly hide it with .hide()
}
```